# Why smtp.gmail.com returns Unrecognized command?

Tags: winapi, smtp, winsock

I've written a winsock client
that connects with smtp.gmail, but after the first 
EHLO command, every other command would return Unrecognized
command. I tryed AUTH, AUTH LOGIN, MAIL...but all
return the same thing. Where do I find the commands
that works with this server, I think they use SMTP commands differently

Comment: You must use encryption for gmail.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using an RFC 3207 SMTP/TLS server.  Check here for more information: [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207).